# Would this style of relating of tables work?

Tags: ms-access

Would the following relationships between the tables work out?

1. There are over 4000 rows for Airline Data, 150k rows for RAW DATA and
   about 2000 rows for Airports.
2. I cannot create a primary key for RAW DATA because there are many repeated values.

http://i108.photobucket.com/albums/n32/lurker3345/ACCESSHELP-1.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relationships look fine.  I assume many things -- for starters, that the data types match where they are linked.  The diagram doesn't communicate much, and there could be many reasons why the schema shown is not optimal.

You certainly can create a PK for RAW DATA, and you had better because it is voluminous.

A common approach is to select multiple fields to serve as the key because together they  obtain a unique value.  This is called a compound key.  It's helpful (even essential) because it naturally ensures the unique combination is not unintentially duplicated.  (In most situations you will want to make sure all key fields are set to not allow a zero-length or null entry.)

There is a simpler approach that serves many situations.  Maybe you don't need this kind of data integrity, or you aren't sure yet what would make up a compound key, or you just want to get a provisional PK in place.  Merely add an autonumber field and declare that as PK.

Some developers take that easy approach and accomplish data validation outside the table...and some ignore data validation needs, which can result in a disaster.

Once you have the PK declared, making sure the table has indexes on critical fields (in addition to the PK) is important for efficiency.

Really, before all else, do yourself a favor and rename all tables and fields so there are no spaces.  While at it, rethink every name and try for most descriptive and standardized name possible.   Access is cruel when it comes to renaming things later on.  Avoiding spaces is a practice that will help you greatly further down the road.

Comment: Thank you very much Smandoli. This definitely helped me a great deal :)